# when I do the spiders by using scrapy in Mac with python3, this error occurs:

Tags: python, scrapy

when I start the spiders by using scrapy in Mac, this problem occurs:

```
2018-01-22 14:43:41 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: baidu)
2018-01-22 14:43:41 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: 
{'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'baidu.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': 
['baidu.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'baidu'}
```

Comment: Please add your codeblock and the steps you have performed to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not any problem it is just log information, showing the settings which you have provided in your `settings.py` file.